# Tee remove chars from file and not the console output

Tags: sed, tee

I want to output a command's results to both the console and a file. For that, I use `tee`. But I would also like to remove the ESC character from the file and not from the console output because it removes the colouring.
I have tried using `sed -e 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'`, which removes the colouring and ESC from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably capture the file and then, when it's done, post-process the file to remove the unwanted characters.

If you need to do it on the fly, and if you use a shell with process substitutions (`>(...)`), then you could use one of these to filter the file output of `tee`:

```bash
some-command | tee >( sed -e 's/\x1b[[0-9;]m//g' >file )
```

Assuming `some-command` still outputs coloured text when it's not connected to a terminal, this would filter the output through your `sed` command before passing the modified output on to the file called `file`.  The unmodified output of `some-command` is also passed to the standard output of `tee` as expected.

Without process substitutions, this could be with `sed` alone like so:

```bash
some-command | sed -n -e p -e 's/\x1b[[0-9;]m//g' -e 'w file'
```

This uses `sed` to output the unmodified line to standard output (with `p`) and then modifies with your substitution expression.  In the end, the modified line is written to `file` with the `w` command.  The default output of the modified line at the end of the editing script is turned off with `-n`.